# SharePoint RefinementWebPart with custom Scope

Tags: search-results, refinement-panel

I customized a (SharePoint 2010 Search not Fast) `RefinementWebPart` by setting the `FilterCategoriesDefinition` attribute with the following XML:

```
<FilterCategories>
  <Category     
    Title="DocumentType"     
    Description="Use this filter to restrict results authored by a specific document Type"     
    Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.ManagedPropertyFilterGenerator"     
    MetadataThreshold="5"     
    NumberOfFiltersToDisplay="15"     
    MaxNumberOfFilters="20"     
    SortBy="Frequency"     
    SortByForMoreFilters="Name"     
    SortDirection="Descending"     
    SortDirectionForMoreFilters="Ascending"     
    ShowMoreLink="False"     
    MappedProperty="DocumentType"     
    MoreLinkText="show more"     
    LessLinkText="show fewer"     />
</FilterCategories>
```

The Filter works fine with the default Search Scope. I created a custom Scope which filters on a few Content Types. When I use this Scope the `RefinementWebPart` isn't showing any result.

Any Ideas, what the problem could be?

Comment: Are there actually any items remaining in the custom scope that have the "DocumentType" property and are there more than 5 results?

Answer (score 0):

If all the items in your scope is of the same DocumentType, then there is nothing to refine on and the web part hides the refiner :)